# If MySQL value empty echo, else echo?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo "No explanation entered." if the health_info value is empty in the MySQL database with the below code.  However, no matter if the row is empty or not, it always echos "No explanation entered."  What am I missing or doing wrong?  Thanks!!

```
<?php   
    if (empty($health_info)) {
        echo "No explanation entered.";
    } else {
        echo $health_info;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$health_info` come from?

Comment: with this code there is no mysql code here so where does $health_info come from and what is the variable? if you answer this then the community will be able to help you better!

Comment: Have you tried just echo-ing $health_info? To see if there is indeed something there

Comment: Make sure that $health_info is really reflecting what you have in your database.

Comment: $health_info is being selected from a MySQL query that is also selecting various other data.

Comment: @tjb1982 his code will show the varible or give the string he specified so you can see where the error is. the error is proberly in how he is getting the info for the variable

Comment: @Nick post the code on how you are getting the mysql data! then we can help

Comment: `$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM appFamily f, appCamper c, appRelease r WHERE f.uniqid = c.uniqid AND f.uniqid = r.uniqid AND c.id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());'`

Comment: in your code you have not assigned $health_info any data from the database. you just use query and result! also are you sure your mysql string is reading the data. This being the case the variable will always be empty!

Comment: By using this code it works:

`<?php 
   if (empty ($row->health_info)) {
      echo "No explanation submitted.";
   } else {
      echo $row->health_info;
   }
?>`

Comment: This is because you are now assigning the data from the database into the variable. This means that whatever is in the database will now be in the variable. And won't be empty

Comment: Before you try to figure out what's wrong with `$health_info`, you might want to fix the gaping SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
    if (empty($health_info)) {
        echo "No explanation entered.";
    } else {
        echo $health_info;
    }
?>
```

In your code you are evaluating $health_info that is undefined (if the code is what you posted).

Do a `var_dump( $health_info );` and you will know what the value is.

Comment: Read the statement!! It executes that code when it's empty! What is the point checking the value when we already know its empty? He hasn't assigned it a value from his statement so it will always be empty